# Способ, который лично мне очень нравится, — это

Tags: пунктуация

> Способ, который лично мне очень нравится, — [это] <...>.

Слово *это* я взял в квадратные скобки, потому что в моём тексте я его сознательно пропустил, для краткости.

Какой знак препинания нужно поставить после *нравится*? Одну лишь запятую, тире или оба?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ставится тире с запятой (она, чтобы закрыть придаточное).
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144 — пункт 2.
Там есть пример, где "это" тоже опущено:
*Самое лучшее, что он мог сделать, — [это] вовремя уйти.*